# How to Obtain the IP address of Databricks Cluster

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to setup a connection from Databricks to an SFTP server. However, before I can connect I will need to let the administrators of the SFTP the ip address of the Databricks cluster to allow access via the ip address. Therefore, can someone let me know how to obtain the ip address of the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the SFTP server is located - in the internal network on outside of your network.

If former (internal SFTP), then you can give admins IP range of the private subnet - IP addresses of the cluster may change over the time.

if it's external SFTP server, then just do `%sh curl -s ifconfig.me` in the notebook, and it will give you address of the NAT gateway. But in this case, it will be shared by multiple resources deployed on Azure.  Also, NAT gateway may have multiple IPs - in this case just ask your network admin.